# Why does the .Find() method in Excel VBA appear to only check the first 15 characters?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, find

I have en Excel List with ID's and Data(About 8000 Rows and more).
The ID's can be only digits oder Digits with charaters. Like "**2222222222222223**" or "**222222222222222A**" (the Cells with the ID are formatted as Text)

If i try to find the Entry Address with a ID, it will insert a now row, because it will not find them. What means that at the End i have Doubled all Entries.

**So my Question is, how many characters does the find method compare?**

```
With objSheet
     strAdresseExcel = .Cells.Find(What:=str, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _ 
     LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Address
    End with
```

So i created a dummy List with 8000 Rows where all the ID's had the Number "**2222222222222222**" and i found something out.

That Excel compares only the first 15 characters if there are only Digits in the String but i works fine if there is a Letter in the ID! You can see the issue in the Image below

Information to the Image:
Row A: 
i worked with Conditional Formatting.
(On the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cells Rules, Duplicate Values)
Works only when the ID has Digits or there is a difference in the first 15 Characters.

Row B: 
I worked with a Formula. (**=IF(COUNTIF(A:A;A2)>1;"Double";"")**)
How you can see, the same Problem happens here as well.

[image]

Comment: Yeah the question is very intresting. The question is, does the .cells.find method in vba compares only the first 15 digits or does it compare the whole string.

Comment: I've updated your question title to try and make it a bit clearer what exactly it is that you're asking.

Comment: `Find` should work up to 255 characters. How are you declaring `str` (bad name for a variable BTW) and how are you assigning values to it? COUNTIF tries to convert things to numbers if it can and you're hitting the 15 digits of precision issue with your numeric strings.

Comment: @MacroMan thanks for the editing

Comment: Works for me with a proper string `str`. Does what you describe if I pass a number.

Comment: @Rory it was a writing mistake with str. it's str1. str1 gets the value from a Object. "str1 = objXMLHEader.DeviceID.ToString()"   (2) thanks for the tip with the countif

Comment: Is `str1` actually declared as a String?

Comment: @Rory Yes, "Dim str1 As String"

Comment: Is it actually the same `str1` from the same scope? Can you post [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me, unless I'm missing something, which is entirely possible :)

It returns the first address where the cell matched and prints out the lengths of the strings searched. I have the data set setup in Sheet1 just as shown, with the numeric data being stored as Text (I added an apostrophe at the start of each value)

```
 Sub testSO()
    Dim objSheet   As Worksheet: Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim strToFind  As String: strToFind = "22222222222222222222222"
    Dim strAddress As String

    strAddress = objSheet.Cells.Find(strToFind, objSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
    LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Address

    'Print out findings
    Debug.Print strAddress, Len(strToFind), Len(objSheet.Range(strAddress))
End Sub
```

Output is:

`$A$5           23            23`

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out, `COUNTIF()` will parse values as numeric where possible before comparing.

> Although Excel can display 30 decimal places, its precision for a specified number is confined to **15 significant figures**, and calculations may have an accuracy that is even less due to three issues: round off, truncation, and binary storage.

[image]

As you can see in the example, the 16-digit values that can be converted to integers are compared by their first 15 significant digits, so it appears as if there are 10 occurrences of each in the column, while strings having letters are correctly evaluated by `COUNTIF()` as unique within the column.

I could not reproduce this issue with VBA `.Find()` but conditional formatting by duplicates shows the same behavior as `COUNTIF()`.

More on the issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: The OP is using `COUNTIF` only as a test. They are interested in the behaviour of `Range.Find`.

Comment: Thansk for the Infromation.